# Different "fancy headers" across one document

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am aiming to typeset a manual of procedures. For the sake of simplicity, I will use same code as in my previous question:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{framed, color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.64, 0.64, 0.82}

\begin{document}
\begin{flushright}
\textsl{\textcolor{red}{Procurement  Protocol \textnumero 001}}\\
\today
\end{flushright}
\begin{center}
\textbf{{\Large     Protocols for Safe Procurement of Specimens \\
Procurement  Protocol \textnumero 001}}
\end{center}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\linespread{1.5}\selectfont
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\textbf{Procurement \textnumero:} \dotfill
\textbf{Procurement date:} \dotfill
\textbf{Shipment type:} \dotfill
\textbf{Received by:} \dotfill
\textbf{Received on date:} \dotfill
\textbf{Country of origin:} \dotfill
\end{multicols}
\begin{shaded}
\centering\Large\bfseries Exemplary Specimen:
\end{shaded}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\begin{flushright}
\textsl{\textcolor{red}{Procurement  Protocol \textnumero \textbf{002}}}\\
\today
\end{flushright}
\begin{center}
\textbf{{\Large     Protocols for Safe Procurement of Specimens \\
            Procurement  Protocol \textnumero \textbf{002}}}
\end{center}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\linespread{1.5}\selectfont
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\textbf{Procurement \textnumero:} \dotfill
\textbf{Procurement date:} \dotfill
\textbf{Shipment type:} \dotfill
\textbf{Received by:} \dotfill
\textbf{Received on date:} \dotfill
\textbf{Country of origin:} \dotfill
\end{multicols}
\begin{shaded}
\centering\Large\bfseries Exemplary Specimen:
\end{shaded}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

The document should contain a set of short (5-7 pp) instructions. As per requirements, each instruction should bear a "number stamp" in either left or right top corner of the page, as you can see in the image below.
[image]
Of course, I can add "number stamp"  manually with `\flushright` environment, as in the "example" code, but is there a way to accomplish this in semi-automatic manner? I am aware of packages `fancyhdr` and `xwatermark` that might be used for this purpose. My question is: how to make "`fancyhdr`" produce different headers through different ranges of pages? I.e. pages 1 - 5 have "No 1" in right corner; pages 6 to 11 have "No 2" end so forth. Thank you for helping me with this!

Comment: I would highly recommend some reusale macros so you have a consistent output.

Comment: It would be nice, but writing a macro is way beyond my modest knowledge of LaTeX. I am thinking of something like defining as many "page styles" as many "forms" I'll have and then using them one by one, or doing it manually (if no solution exists).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would define some macros to produce a consistent layout along with a counter that steps with every new protocol.

[image: usersxFancyhdr]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{framed, color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.64, 0.64, 0.82}


\newcounter{procurement}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ohead{\textcolor{red}{Procurement  Protocol \textnumero~\theprocurement}\\\today}
\setlength{\headheight}{34.0pt}
\newcommand{\nextprotocol}{% automatic title on a new page
\clearpage
\refstepcounter{procurement}
\begin{center}
\textbf{\large     Protocols for Safe Procurement of Specimens \\
Procurement  Protocol \textnumero~\theprocurement}
\end{center}
}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newcommand{\showEx}{%
\begin{shaded}
\centering\Large\bfseries Exemplary Specimen:
\end{shaded}
}



\begin{document}


\nextprotocol
\begin{tabular}{p{.47\linewidth}p{.47\linewidth}}
{Procurement \textnumero:} \dotfill &
{Procurement date:} \dotfill \\
{Shipment type:} \dotfill &
{Received by:} \dotfill \\
{Received on date:} \dotfill &
{Country of origin:} \dotfill \\
\end{tabular}

\showEx

\lipsum[1]


\nextprotocol
\begin{tabular}{p{.47\linewidth}p{.47\linewidth}}
{Procurement \textnumero:} \dotfill &
{Procurement date:} \dotfill \\
{Shipment type:} \dotfill &
{Received by:} \dotfill \\
{Received on date:} \dotfill &
{Country of origin:} \dotfill \\
\end{tabular}
\showEx
\lipsum[2]




\nextprotocol
\begin{tabular}{p{.47\linewidth}p{.47\linewidth}}
{Procurement \textnumero:} \dotfill &
{Procurement date:} \dotfill \\
{Shipment type:} \dotfill &
{Received by:} \dotfill \\
{Received on date:} \dotfill &
{Country of origin:} \dotfill \\
\end{tabular}
\showEx
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

If the number is not numerical, but an arbitrary string, you can still use a simple text macro to fill in the header.

%Without a counter but an arbitrary string

[image: usersxFancyhdrExtended]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{framed, color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.64, 0.64, 0.82}


\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\newcommand{\thisprocurement}{}
\ohead{\textcolor{red}{Procurement  Protocol \textnumero~\thisprocurement}\\\today}
\setlength{\headheight}{34.0pt}
\newcommand{\nextprotocol}[1][Not defined. Attention]{% automatic title on a new page
\clearpage
\renewcommand{\thisprocurement}{#1}
\begin{center}
\textbf{\large     Protocols for Safe Procurement of Specimens \\
Procurement  Protocol \textnumero~\thisprocurement}
\end{center}
}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newcommand{\showEx}{%
\begin{shaded}
\centering\Large\bfseries Exemplary Specimen:
\end{shaded}
}



\begin{document}


\nextprotocol[Wombat12]
\begin{tabular}{p{.47\linewidth}p{.47\linewidth}}
{Procurement \textnumero:} \dotfill &
{Procurement date:} \dotfill \\
{Shipment type:} \dotfill &
{Received by:} \dotfill \\
{Received on date:} \dotfill &
{Country of origin:} \dotfill \\
\end{tabular}

\showEx

\lipsum[1]


\nextprotocol[Capybara.42]
\begin{tabular}{p{.47\linewidth}p{.47\linewidth}}
{Procurement \textnumero:} \dotfill &
{Procurement date:} \dotfill \\
{Shipment type:} \dotfill &
{Received by:} \dotfill \\
{Received on date:} \dotfill &
{Country of origin:} \dotfill \\
\end{tabular}
\showEx
\lipsum[2]




\nextprotocol
\begin{tabular}{p{.47\linewidth}p{.47\linewidth}}
{Procurement \textnumero:} \dotfill &
{Procurement date:} \dotfill \\
{Shipment type:} \dotfill &
{Received by:} \dotfill \\
{Received on date:} \dotfill &
{Country of origin:} \dotfill \\
\end{tabular}
\showEx
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, Johannes! It is an interesting solution, it does work automatically! If I may ask: how do you think is a solution that does not involve custom counter possible? Instead, is it possible to use some cross-referencing? For example, to put something like  `\ohead{\textcolor{red}{Procurement  Protocol \textnumero~\ref{#1}}\\\today}
\setlength{\headheight}{34.0pt}` for the page header and `\begin{center} \textbf{\large Protocols for Safe Procurement of Specimens \\ Procurement Protocol \textnumero~001\label{#1}} \end{center} }` for text body.

Comment: @user136555 In order to use label ref, you need a counter. My example is already set up for that. You can simply use them.

Comment: Play around a bit,  i'll be back in 6 hours.

Comment: In other words, I should put something like `ABC001\label{\theprocurement}`. Am I getting it right?

Comment: Finally I managed to create something that does the job the way I want it, albeit, using this piece of code `\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setword}[2]{%
  \phantomsection
  #1\def\@currentlabel{\unexpanded{#1}}\label{#2}%
}
\makeatothe` from other question.

Comment: @user136555 It seems you are obsessed with labels. Why are you trying to use labels for the purpose? A counter does the job just fine. Or do you want to store any string? Use a simple macro in that case. If i would be able to understand what you are trying to achieve exactly, i might be able to help better, but i don't have a clue.

Comment: Sorry, if I not clear: my ultimate goal is to be able to put some alphanumerical number after `\textnumero` in this piece of code `\begin{center}
\textbf{{\Large     Protocols for Safe Procurement of Specimens \\
Procurement  Protocol \textnumero 001}}
\end{center}` (lets call it protocol header) and have it replicated as a "stamp" in top right corner through the length of given protocol in the manual. The counter works fine for numbering, the problem is  numbers: they are alphanumerical and not continuous, i.e. first protocol will be numbered AB.00.25, the next one will be EF.00.33 etc.

Comment: In essence,  "arbitrary" number(due to (specific coding requirements)) of a particular protocol must be entered manually after number sign  and then replicated as a corner stamp in all pages of the protocol. Next protocol - another number. I did the "stamping" with simple `fancyhdr` when I made these protocols as separate documents, but in book this will not work.

Comment: One more question:  you reference `\usepackage{mwepage}` I have MiTex2.9 plus TeXStudio. I wanted to install this package (to test your code), but cannot find it, using Package Manager, neither can I find it on CTAN. Am I missing something?

Comment: @user136555 Sorry, my fault. It is a local package on my machine responsible for the mild yellow backround. You can remove it.

Comment: I got it, after some googling. Actually, the page background look amazing - it perfectly mimics "old"  paper appearance. I use `\pagecolor` for this purpose. If I may ask, what color is it? It is not exactly `ivory`. is it ? I use latexcolors com for color-definitions.

Comment: @user136555 `yellow!20!white`. It is very simple -> https://github.com/johannesbottcher/mwepage/blob/master/mwepage.sty

Comment: Einfach genial !!!